# Install to-be-continuous on a non-root group in a self-managed GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

Starting the Gitlab CI for a project on a self-managed Gitlab, I would like to use the [to-be-continuous](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous) templates.

So I wanted to follow the [dedicated documentation](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/self-managed/basic/), which requires a public root group `to-be-continuous` on our Gitlab.

But, for some company purpose, my request for creating this group at the root has been internally refused. As a response, they asked me why the to-be-continuous path isn't variabilized.

How can I workaround this ? Shouldn't it be a good idea to variabilize this path ?

I tried to create a sub_group on Gitlab (non-root) and follow the instructions but giving to the script at https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/tools/gitlab-sync/-/raw/master/gitlab-sync.sh the argument `DEST_SYNC_PATH`.

The project was well imported, but since the templates references are hard coded, any to-be-continuous internal reference is failing.

[See the issue on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/tools/gitlab-sync/-/issues/15)